# When running `term` in standalone emacs on OSX, how can I copy output?

Tags: osx, term, copy-paste

This question maybe sounds a bit strange, but I can't for the life of me work out how to copy output from `term` when it is running in the standalone version ("standalone" as in when emacs runs in its own GUI window). None of the standard emacs or OSX keybindings or mouseclicks seem to work.

How do you copy text from `term` on emacs on OSX?

Comment: selecting text w/ the mouse, and doing `Cmd-C` _worksforme_. are you sure Emacs has focus?

Comment: @nega yes, that works _within_ emacs, but I can't seem to copy to the OSX system clipboard

Comment: by default the standard cmd-c/cmd-v works. you'll need to add more details to your question. what emacs are you using? are you using `emacs -Q`? does emacs have focus? are you using some kind of clipboard manager? etc.

Comment: is your shell init to blame? have you moved it aside or short circuited it?

Comment: "by default the standard cmd-c/cmd-v works" This isn't standard on emacs- or am I missing something? In any case it doesn't work for me when running "M-x term" on emacs on OSX. (I can of course use cmd-c/cmd-v if I am running "emacs -nw" in a terminal)

Comment: You're missing something. If you want further help, you'll need to update your question with more details, or answer the questions in my previous comments. Good luck.

Comment: Answers to questions: using normal vanilla Emacs from launcher in OSX, not using emacs -Q, Emacs has focus, no clipboard manager, no shell init (am not initing from a shell).